# Is it still recommended to use sleepd?

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I want to suspend or hibernate 14.04  on T400, if batter is low. The system settings for power managenet only has option for shut down, and doesn't have option for suspend, and the option for hibernate is grey out.

I found sleepd at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/sleepd.8.html. It seems to do the work. but it seems not avail for 14.04.

Its website is http://joeyh.name/code/sleepd/

So is sleepd still recommended for use?
btw, If not, what do you recommend to use?

Thanks.